# How can I stop changing style in firemonkey in ScaleChanged message

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-style

I use Firemokey 10.2. In macOS, internally when you move your from from a normal display to a retina display it automatically changes style of the controls. I would like to stop this message which is TScaleChangedMessage. I would appreciate If you could help me how can I stop this message in my app. In other word how can I stop changing from normal styles to High-Resolution Styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, 
changing this function 
`function TMacWindowHandle.GetScale: Single;
begin
  //Result := Wnd.backingScaleFactor
  result := 1;
end;`
will solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a copy of the FMX.Platform.Mac unit, and modify the TFMXWindow.windowDidChangeBackingProperties method so that the message is never sent, e.g:

```
procedure TFMXWindow.windowDidChangeBackingProperties(notification: NSNotification);
begin
//  if (Application = nil) or (Application.Terminated) then
//    Exit;
//  try
//    TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SendMessage(nil, TScaleChangedMessage.Create(Wnd), True);
//  except
//    HandleException(Self);
//  end;
end;
```

i.e. just comment out everything in it

Unfortunately if you're using Delphi 10.2 Update 1, it means you'll need to include **all** the FMX units in the project path (so that they're also recompiled), due to this issue:

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18836

Comment: thanks a million, but unfortunately firemonkey still changes the style when my app runs in retina display and commenting out this method doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: Your question was: "I would like to stop this message which is TScaleChangedMessage. I would appreciate If you could help me how can I stop this message in my app". I answered your question. Unless you edit your question, my answer is correct.